# how to select records which are not in my b table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table A with 100k records and another table B with 500k records .B should have all the 100k records from A with a key in both tables. how to write a query to find records which are missing in B that exists in A. it should not list all other 400k which is not in A.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you care about all the columns, you can use `except`:

```
select a.*
from a
except
select b.*
from b;
```

This assumes that the columns in the table are exactly the same, with compatible types, and defined in the same order.  It is normally better to list the columns explicitly.

Comment: What do you mean with "if you can about"?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
 select * from a 
 left join b on b.id = a.id
 where b.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you can do it by comparing a key/id.  So you could use an anti left join, not exists, in, or except.  Here is 1 method that should preform well for you.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    TableA a
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE a.Id = b.Id)
```